# How do I get the X off the images above the background image in my HTML email template in Dreamweaver?

Tags: html, image, email, background-image, dreamweaver

I'm trying to get my HTML code to work for an email template I am making, and I finally got it to where my background shows for Outlook, however, I am now having problems to where my images above the background is not showing. Whenever I test it to see if the code is working as is, I get a red X where the image should be. I thought perhaps because I have the Trust Center settings not downloading on my email, but when I unchecked it, the images still didn't show up.

Example of what the image shows up as:
[image]

This is the code I have for the following in html:
[image]

Thank you to anyone helping me out with this!

Comment: It may be that you're seeing the background because of the conditional "if gte mso 9" is loading the image rather than the first instance of the background image.  That said, I've seen this error in Outlook because Outlooks default image settings is not to load images unless you click on them.  Is this the case?

Comment: Hi @ja408! I tried clicking the images to load them and I tried to fix the settings to where it would load the images instead and it wouldn't work. I tried making it into a table and the images on top worked but the background image wouldn't load without the "if gte mso 9"

Comment: It could be a compatibility issue also.  Some email clients will not render background images.  Outlook is definitely one of those.

Comment: Ah that could be it. Thanks for your help, @ja408. :)